# Pascal: How to randomize two images on Turbo Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a task of having two images (Two TImage), one a head and the other a tail (Coins), on my screen with a TButton to randomize both of them.

It is to be that when you press the button, the two images go random choosing Heads or Tails.

I know its kind of a easy question, but I am just learning. I just don't know what to use!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sample from a discrete uniform distribution with two possible values. So like this:

```
function IsHead: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Random()<0.5;
end;
```

Or like this:

```
function IsHead: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Random(2)=0;
end;
```

You'll want to call `Randomize` somewhere in the startup of your program to make sure that you don't get the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers each time you run the program.

I'm assuming that you already know how to write button `OnClick` event handlers, and switch visibility of `TImage` controls.